# Matrix implementation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I put this together for a task and thought some feedback would be useful.

```
class Matrix<T : Ring<T>>(val size: Size, init: (x: Int, y: Int) -> T) : Ring<Matrix<T>> {
    init {
        require(size.x > 0 && size.y > 0) { "Zero size Matrix is invalid." }
    }

    // Use a list of lists for the data
    private val a: List<List<T>> = List(size.y) { y -> List(size.x) { x -> init.invoke(x, y) } }

    // NB: These are memoised `zero` and `one` of T, not Matrix<T>
    private val zero: T = a[0][0].zero()
    private val one: T = a[0][0].one()

    // Allows matrix[x,y]
    operator fun get(x: Int, y: Int): T = a[y][x]

    // Entrywise sum
    override operator fun plus(b: Matrix<T>): Matrix<T> {
        require(size == b.size) { "Matrix addition requires matrices of the same size. ($size != ${b.size})" }
        return Matrix(size) { x, y -> this[x, y] + b[x, y] }
    }

    // Normal matrix multiply
    override operator fun times(b: Matrix<T>): Matrix<T> {
        require(size.x == b.size.y) { "Matrix multiplication requires the same number of columns in the multiplicand as rows in the multiplier. (${size.x} != ${b.size.y})" }
        return Matrix(Size(b.size.x, size.y)) { x, y ->
            (0 until size.x).sumBy { n -> this[n, y] * b[x, n] }
        }
    }

    // Scalar multiply
    operator fun times(c: T): Matrix<T> = Matrix(size) { x, y -> this[x, y] * c }

    // zero() and one() are memoized - not sure if this is worthwhile.
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun zero(): Matrix<T> = ZEROS.computeIfAbsent(Pair(size, zero)) {
        Matrix(size) { _, _ -> zero }
    } as Matrix<T>

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun one(): Matrix<T> = ONES.computeIfAbsent(Triple(size, zero, one)) {
        Matrix(size) { x, y -> if (x == y) one else zero }
    } as Matrix<T>

    // Transpose.
    fun transpose(): Matrix<T> = Matrix(Size(size.y, size.x)) { x, y -> this[y, x] }

    // Power
    fun pow(n: Int): Matrix<T> = pow(n.toBigInteger())

    // Using Exponentiation by Squaring - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring
    fun pow(n: BigInteger): Matrix<T> = when (n) {
        BigInteger.ZERO -> one()
        BigInteger.ONE -> this
        else -> {
            val v = (this * this).pow(n shr 1)
            if(n.testBit(0)) v * this else v
        }
    }

    // pow(2^n) - Just square it n times.
    fun pow2n(n: Int): Matrix<T> = (0 until n).fold(this) { v, _ -> v * v }

    fun row(i: Int): Iterable<T> = a[i].asIterable()
    fun col(i: Int): Iterable<T> = a.map { it[i] }

    // Normal sumBy returns `Int` - I want a T
    private inline fun Iterable<Int>.sumBy(selector: (Int) -> T): T = this.fold(zero) { v, i -> v + selector(i) }

    override fun toString(): String =
        "{${size}:${if (size.y > 1) "\n" else ""}" +
                a.joinToString(prefix = "[", separator = "]\n[", postfix = "]") {
                    it.joinToString(separator = ",") { v -> v.toString() }
                } +
                "}"

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false
        return (a == (other as Matrix<*>).a)
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int = a.hashCode()

    companion object {
        // Multitons for zero and one so we don't create more than we need and equals will shortcut.
        // The zeros map is keyed on the size and zero of the field.
        private val ZEROS: ConcurrentMap<Pair<Size, Ring<*>>, Matrix<*>> = ConcurrentHashMap()

        // The ones map is keyed on the size, zero AND one of the field.
        private val ONES: ConcurrentMap<Triple<Size, Ring<*>, Ring<*>>, Matrix<*>> = ConcurrentHashMap()
    }
}
```

Here's `Ring`

```
/**
 * Defines an object with operators + and *, a zero and an identity
 *
 * Technically this is actually an `Rng` but Ring is close enough and easier to say.
 *
 * See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)
 */
interface Ring<T> {
    operator fun plus(b: T): T
    operator fun times(b: T): T
    fun zero(): T
    fun one(): T
}
```

Here's a `BigInteger` implementation of `Ring`.

```
data class BigIntegerRing(private val v: BigInteger) : Ring<BigIntegerRing> {

    override fun zero(): BigIntegerRing = ZERO

    override fun one(): BigIntegerRing = ONE

    override fun plus(b: BigIntegerRing): BigIntegerRing = BigIntegerRing(v + b.v)

    override fun times(b: BigIntegerRing): BigIntegerRing = BigIntegerRing(v * b.v)

    override fun toString() = v.toString()

    companion object {
        val ZERO: BigIntegerRing = BigIntegerRing(BigInteger.ZERO)
        val ONE: BigIntegerRing = BigIntegerRing(BigInteger.ONE)

        // Make a matrix from Ints
        fun matrix(size: Size, init: (x: Int, y: Int) -> Int): Matrix<BigIntegerRing> =
            Matrix(size) { x, y -> BigIntegerRing(init(x, y).toBigInteger()) }
    }
}
```

And a Galois Field(2) Ring.

```
enum class GF2 : Ring<GF2> {
    ZERO, ONE;

    override fun zero(): GF2 = ZERO

    override fun one(): GF2 = ONE

    // plus -> xor
    override fun plus(b: GF2): GF2 = if (this === b) ZERO else ONE

    // times -> and
    override fun times(b: GF2): GF2 = if (this === ONE && b === ONE) ONE else ZERO

    override fun toString(): String = ordinal.toString()

    companion object {
        // Factory from boolean.
        operator fun invoke(b: Boolean): GF2 = if (b) ONE else ZERO

        // Make a matrix
        fun matrix(size: Size, init: (x: Int, y: Int) -> GF2): Matrix<GF2> = Matrix(size, init)
    }
}
```

And of course `Size` is trivial.

```
data class Size(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
    override fun toString() = "(${x}x${y})"
}
```